# Wrong Relative Directory Path: Unable to Import GraphQl files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, directory, graphql

I am trying to import a mutation from my GraphQL file into my LoginPage file like this:

```
import LoginMutation from '../../graphql/login-mutation';
```

but I keep getting an error that:

```
import LoginMutation from '../../graphql/login-mutation';
```

The mutation is present in the login-mutation file of my GraphQL folder. So most probably the path I am entering is wrong. Could someone please have a look at the picture of my directory structure and help me correct the path?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the extension of your file at the end of your route.